# Only default permalink is working mod_rewrite enabled

Tags: permalinks, htaccess, mod-rewrite

My problem is in my wordpress site only default permalinks is working.. When I change permalinks all pages become not found.. only home page is showing.

When I change permalinks to postname .htaccess content change to

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

And for default it is

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# END WordPress
```

Also tried to get the status of mod_rewrite using this

```
in_array( 'mod_rewrite', apache_get_modules() )
```

It returns 1 and mod_rewrite is enabled on my server.
I have gone through all the documents available in internet.. Please help me to solve this problem..
My hosting server is godaddy..

Answer (score 1):

GoDaddy is unique among hosts that I've seen in that the changes you make to .htaccess files don't take place immediately. They use some caching system for them in some manner.

Turn on the permalinks and wait a day. It's worked for me in the past when I used to be hosted there.

Comment: Thank you for your response.. But I cant down the site for 1 day.. :(

Comment: Blame GoDaddy, not me. Nothing we can do about it. You might try making an .htaccess file with those rules in it anyway, but not actually switching the permalinks, then waiting a day before giving it a try.

Comment: I am not blaming you sir.. Contacting Go-daddy support.. But they not giving any solution.. :(

Comment: You are using their Linux hosting, correct? Things like .htaccess won't work on their Windows hosting systems. Switch to the Linux systems.

Comment: Yes. I am using their Linux hosting. Deluxe package..

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue, only the default permalink working with Apache mod-rewrite enabled.

Other sources had us tweaking the AllowOverride in the 'Directory "var/www/html"' from 'None' to 'All', this only resulted in a 500 error when anything but the default permalink was chosen.

Sometimes giving it rest and coming back to it works -- after sleeping on it overnight, we reviewed the http.conf file closely and saw this in the PidFile Section...

```
    PidFile run/httpd.pid
```

When doing a 'find / -name httpd.pid', we discovered this is NOT the correct path, so we changed it accordingly...

```
    PidFile /var/run/httpd/httpd.pid
```

Saved the file (with AllowOverride set to All as well) and restarted apache...

```
    service httpd restart
```

The default permalink was already set in WP so we chose another, saved and...

All is well with life once again...

:-)